# Build fails on latest ubuntu in github actions with std::sort but passes without std::sort

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, github-actions

I am trying to do something seemingly trivial: use the `std::sort` function on a `std::vector<float>`. The issue is one I can't seem to find an answer for. For reference, here is the first bit of the function I am using:

```
std::vector<std::string> MassDawg::search(std::vector<float> sequence, int ppmTol){
    MassDawgNode * currentNode = this->root;

    if (sequence.empty()) return std::vector<std::string> {};

    std::sort(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), std::less<float>());
```

**Note** I have tried using this sort function without the `std::less<float>()` with the same issue.

This code runs perfectly on my MacBook pro (2016 13inch on macOS 10.15.5). It compiles and runs perfectly fine on my laptop using C++11. The problem comes with my push to github. I have an action setup as follows:

```
name: build and test

# Controls when the action will run. Triggers the workflow on push or pull request
# events but only for the master branch
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
    # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    # Runs a set of commands using the runners shell
    - name: Build and test 
      run: |
        chmod u+x build_and_test_cc.sh
        echo Building and testing
        ./build_and_test_cc.sh
        echo Done
```

My the shell script `./build_and_test_cc` is a small one that simply runs my makefile and and runs my unittests (I use `catch.h`).

Again, the problem only occurs AFTER I add the sort function. If I remove this line, it works fine. Here is my makefile.

```
# Variables 
CC = clang++
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c++11

# Executable
main: main.o MassDawg.o MassDawgNode.o utils.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o main main.o MassDawg.o MassDawgNode.o utils.o

test: test.o MassDawg.o MassDawgNode.o utils.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o test test.o MassDawg.o MassDawgNode.o utils.o

# Object files
main.o: main.cpp MassDawg.hpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.cpp

test.o: test.cpp MassDawg.hpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c test.cpp

MassDawg.o: MassDawg.hpp MassDawgNode.hpp utils.hpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c MassDawg.cpp 

MassDawgNode.o: MassDawgNode.hpp 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c MassDawgNode.cpp

utils.o: utils.hpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c utils.cpp

clean:
    rm main test *.o
```

My strong suit is not makefiles, so it could very well be the problem. I am completely perplexed and have no idea what could be causing this. Thanks

Comment: What is your proof that the rest of the code, that's not shown, doesn't have a bug that results in undefined and memory corruption, which results in crashes only on whichever architecture and compiler that this github action uses -- in which case this has nothing to do with any makefile, whatsoever, but with the bug in the code that's not shown, and nobody will be able to help you with?

Comment: Is `#include <algorithm>` in the code that uses algorithms?

Comment: @TedLyngmo The code is in a file called "MassDawg.cpp" and the `#include <algorithms>` is in its header file

Comment: @Zach The problem with not providing a [mcve] is that people have to guess/ask.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Any suggestions on what else to add to this? It only happens when the one line is added to the code. What other context would be helpful?

Comment: Create a [mcve].

Comment: If your "build fails", what is the exact error message from the compiler or linker?

Comment: @rveerd the only message I get from github is "Process completed with exit code 127."

Comment: Is there any reason why you won't create a [mcve]?

Comment: Its not clear to me what I'm missing to not have the minimal reproducible example. I'm not sure if you mean I have too much or not enough code

Comment: @Zach A [mcve] contains the minimum amount of code to reproduce the problem. Your code doesn't compile as-is so make a small program that you expect to be compilable. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/vehj8a)

Comment: Btw, why is `<algorithm>` included in the header file? I don't see it being included: [MassDawg.hpp](https://github.com/zmcgrath96/mass_DAWG/blob/master/src/MassDawg.hpp) I noticed `using namespace std;` in the header file though. Never do that in header files.